# Can branch.io fingerprint a device via the Web-SDK and track this device through install?

Tags: branch.io

I am interested in using branch.io to provide source attribution of the user of my application. However, I would prefer not to redirect the user to a new URL and to keep them on internal URLs.

Right now, what we do is:
Apps Website -> Send SMS/Email with branch short link -> user clicks link -> directed to branch -> redirects to apps store -> install -> branch attributes correctly yay!

What I'd like to do is:
Apps website -> Send SMS/Email with special apps URL online that invokes branch.io Web SDK to fingerprint user -> direct to app store -> install -> branch connects the web sdk fingerprint to the app install

Is this possible? I guess my question revolves around what happens when we call setIdentity? Does that call send enough fingerprint data to branch servers to be able to identify this device profile on install? Or is the full redirect absolutely necessary to provide enough fingerprinting?

Answer (score 0):

Branch will be able to identify the users through the whole flow you mentioned. That is, Your website -> Text Me the App to send SMS -> Click on the link redirects the user to your mobile website (which has Branch web SDK integrated)-> direct user to App store -> Install the app.

Branch assigns a default Identity ID to each user (called as Branch Identity ID). You can view this in the Liveview Identities tab [here](https://dashboard.branch.io/liveview/identities). Each event in the Liveview Event tab [here](https://dashboard.branch.io/liveview/events) has a Branch Identity ID attached to it.

If you wish to associate a custom ID to the users you should use `setIdentity()` on your website or your App. The analytics will then be tagged with both the `Branch Identity ID` and the custom ID you set (called as `Developer Identity` on the Branch dashboard).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I've attempted to simulate, but am not seeing the linkage occur. If i understand it correctly, the device events will be tracked with the same Branch Identity ID as the web events?

I have a mobile site that injects the web sdk code (just branch.init with my key and then tracks a click event). Site opened w/ mobile safari on my device and my events in liveview with Branch Identity ID. Then, I use xcode simulator to install my test app on the same device (with branch sdk and same key) and i notice the branch identity IDs are different for the web and device. Is this expected?